# How to access value with known key from a nested dictionary

Tags: .net, vb.net, dictionary

I create a dictionary

```
Dim north_dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
```

Inside a For Each loop I

```
Dim dict_north As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

to create a nested dictionary for each key in north_dict

Each nested dictionary has the same 35 keys
example keys y7x1, y7x2...

Without looping through the dictionary how do I retrieve values of known keys from the nested dictionaries?

```
Dim north_files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(txtbx_north_location.Text)

For Each file As String In north_files

    Dim dict_north As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Dim reader_for_files As New StreamReader(file)
    Dim allLines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    Do While Not reader_for_files.EndOfStream
        allLines.Add(reader_for_files.ReadLine())
    Loop

    reader_for_files.Close()

    y7x1 = ReadLine(2, allLines)
    dict_north.Add("y7x1", y7x1)
    y7x2 = ReadLine(4, allLines)
    dict_north.Add("y7x2", y7x2)

    Dim result As String
    result = Path.GetFileName(file)
    north_dict.Add(result, dict_north)
```

Next

such that

```
Dim sbuild As New StringBuilder
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)) In north_dict
    sbuild.AppendLine(item.Key & ") " & item.Value.ToString)
Next
MessageBox.Show(sbuild.ToString)
```

produces results like

NORTH_COL_10ROW_1) System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.String]
NORTH_COL_10ROW_10) System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.String]

I want to be able to get the value of for instance key y7x1 from NORTH_COL_4ROW_2

I do not know yet if the nested dictionaries are being added successfully.

Comment: Something like `sbuild.AppendLine(item.Key & ") " & item.Value("y7x1"))`?

Comment: Thank you Mark I am just learning.

Comment: This shows me my dictionaries are working. Now I must figure out how to access them individually outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have working

```
Dim dictvalue As String = ""
If north_dict("NORTH_COL_4ROW_2").TryGetValue("y7x1", dictvalue) Then
    MessageBox.Show(dictvalue.ToString)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Have thought about using linq? it would be sth. like this. Here is a working example, still not sure if I understood your question right.

```
        For n = 1 To 100

            Dim dict_north As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

            For m = 1 To 35
                dict_north.Add("y7x" & m.ToString(), "Value for y7x " & m.ToString())
            Next

            north_dict.Add(n.ToString(), dict_north)

        Next

        Dim s = (From nd In north_dict
                 From dn In nd.Value
                 Where dn.Key = "y7x2"
                 Select nd.Key & " - " & dn.Value).ToList()

        Debug.Print(String.Join(" ,", s.ToArray()))
```

Result is 
1 - Value for y7x 2 ,2 - Value for y7x 2 ,3 - Value for y7x 2...